# Why execution time of "for($i=1; $i -le 1000000; $i++){}" faster than "for([int]$i=1; $i -le 1000000; $i++){}" in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Sample code:

```
# Step 1
$start = get-date
for($i=1; $i -le 1000000; $i++){}
$end = get-date
($end-$start).TotalMilliseconds
Remove-Variable i

# Step 2
$start = get-date
for([int]$i=1; $i -le 1000000; $i++){}
$end = get-date
($end-$start).TotalMilliseconds
Remove-Variable i

# Step 3
$start = get-date
for([int64]$i=1; $i -le 1000000; $i++){}
$end = get-date
($end-$start).TotalMilliseconds
Remove-Variable i

# Step 4
$start = get-date
for([float]$i=1; $i -le 1000000; $i++){}
$end = get-date
($end-$start).TotalMilliseconds
Remove-Variable i

# Step 5
$start = get-date
for([double]$i=1; $i -le 1000000; $i++){}
$end = get-date
($end-$start).TotalMilliseconds
Remove-Variable i

# Step 6
$start = get-date
for($i=1; $i -le 1000000; $i++){}
$end = get-date
($end-$start).TotalMilliseconds
Remove-Variable i
```

Results:

1845.1056
3160.1808
5029.2877
5521.3158
4504.2576
1804.1032

There are no question about differences between steps 2-6. But differences between 1 and 2 and 6 is inexplicable: $i in theese cases has type "System.Int32".

Comment: I saw roughly the same results as you.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with the way that you are measuring execution time, but for future testing you may want to check this out at a prompt: get-help Measure-Command

Comment: What's interesting is that f you do `$i = new-object -type Int64` or   `$i = new-object -type Int32` and then `for($i=1; $i -le 1000000; $i++){}`, you get similar results across the board (for ints). Something in that cast operator perhaps...

Comment: I have just checked that 1000000 can be replaced with `$ubound` wich is defined as `$ubound = 1000000` or `[int]$ubound = 1000000`. Results are the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a good explanation of the difference between Step 1 and Step 2 just try at the command prompt :

```
Remove-Variable i
Trace-Command -Name TypeConversion -Expression {for($i=1; $i -le 1000000; $i++){}} -PSHost
```

And then :

```
Remove-Variable i
Trace-Command -Name TypeConversion -Expression {for([int]$i=1; $i -le 1000000; $i++){}} -PSHost
```

This confirm @zdan assumption the difference is in the cast that is done in every loop. Step 1 and 6 are the sames.